# BitTorrent encryption in transmission of data

Tags: bittorrent

Correct me if i am wrong with my understanding.

BitTorrent is a protocol used for P2P sharing and It is used by torrent client. BitTorrent protocol have ability to download the files in chunks. Once all the chunks downloaded Torrent client application will add them in a single file.

Is there any encryption method is used while transmission of data by BitTorrent protocol or Torrent application? I have seen BitTorrent was earlier open source but after release version 6 it is no more open source. It is about protocol or BitTorrent Client?

Please clear my doubt.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your question exactly?  There are dozens of free BitTorrent clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to distinguish between the BitTorrent protocol and the BitTorrent clients. There are dozens of BitTorrent clients, one of which is named “BitTorrent” itself for further confusion. This client is proprietary, but many other clients exist, including a lot of free and open source ones.

For the BitTorrent protocol, which is defined in a [free-to-use specification](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html), there are encryption techniques that some of these clients implement. The [Wikipedia article on BitTorrent protocol encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_protocol_encryption) has more information on these techniques and also gives a list of which clients support them.